# How to Set the Navigation Bar Colour in an iOS 8 Launch Screen File?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, interface-builder

I'm using a storyboard for my Launch Screen File. It's a very basic setup:

[image]

I want to set an opaque colour for the navigation bar...

I can do something like the following in the *AppDelegate*:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

But that doesn't apply to the launch screen file.

How do I set the nav bar colour / `barTintColor` in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bar tint is settable for a navigation bar in the Inspector [as shown here](https://hoishing.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/navigation-bar-background-color-and-buttons-tint-color/).

Just checked it with a HOT PINK nav bar in my current project's LaunchScreen.xib and it works fine.

Comment: I should have added that I don't use IB - I'd assumed this was settable in IB, but couldn't work out how to select the navigation bar... thanks for confirming it though - that led to me finding out how to select the navigation bar (I'll add another answer just for anyone else in the same situation). Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

@alexcurylo confirmed that the `barTintColor` can be set in IB. Part of the problem here was that I couldn't figure out how to *select* the `NavigationBar` (I'm not a regular user of Interface Builder)...

Just in case it helps someone else, I was able to select the `Navigation Bar`, as a child of the `Navigation Controller`, using the `Document Outline` pane (I'd failed to do so by left/right clicking on the visual representation...):

[image]

Once selected, as @alexcurylo pointed out, it was simply a setting in the `Attributes Inspector`.